# Blender lagging very hard

Tags: modeling

im creating this frog caracter and all of a sudden blender is lagging very hard.I have some screenshots, i think its the huge spice on thetop of the head, i cant seam to delete it now matter how much i try. If i remmember the lagging[image] started when i did it the first time.